# How do I plot months with integer values using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
months = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)        
totals = c(437318,406597,454125,432062,443323,414061,418627,428530,400509,427900,378849,344718)
test_df = data.frame(months, totals)
```

[image]

I created a plot using the following code:

```
test_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=months, y=totals)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='red3') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=scales::breaks_extended(n=10)) +
  ggtitle('Amount by Month') +
  ylab('Amount') +
  xlab('Month')
```

[image]

ggplot is assuming that the x-axis contains a continuous variable. I assume this is because the test_df$months is of integer type. I tried editing my plot code by first creating an array of month names:

> months =
> c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')

and then adding this to the plot code:

> scale_x_discrete('Month', months)

but this didn't work.

How can I get the x-axis to be displayed with either integer values for the month or month names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt vector `month.abb` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

test_df %>%
  mutate(months = factor(month.abb[months], levels = month.abb)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=months, y=totals)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='red3') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=scales::breaks_extended(n=10)) +
  ggtitle('Amount by Month') +
  ylab('Amount') +
  xlab('Month')
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome. How would you adjust my original code to simply display the number of the month (1,2,...,12)?

Comment: For that you can convert `months` to factor and it should show 1, 2, ...12 instead of values like 2.5 7.5 etc.

Comment: There's no way of initially setting the x-axis variable to be discrete instead continuous?

Comment: `months` variable is continuous by converting it to `factor` we are making it to discrete.

Comment: I got the month numbers to work with `factor`. Thanks you.