# How do I color two different dataframes on one chart using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I color two data series different colors on the same plot?

I combined two different dataframes:

```
ages_test=c('<18','18-24','25-44','45-64','65+',"UNKNOWN")

values_test=c(411694,1313082,2301521,918416,41728,178)
df_test1=data.frame(ages_test,values_test)

values_test=c(134924,350794,612476,228237,10472,49)
df_test2=data.frame(ages_test,values_test)

df_combined = rbind(df_test1, df_test2)
```

[image]

Then I created this plot:

```
df_combined %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=ages_test, y=values_test), label=values_test) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=scales::breaks_extended(n=10), labels=comma) +
  geom_text(hjust=.5, vjust=-1, size=3, aes(label=comma(values_test)))
```

[image]

This chart contains the two different data series and labels for each. I want one of them to be a different color so that I can differentiate between the two.

I tried adding `fill=values_test` to `aes` like so `ggplot(aes(x=ages_test, y=values_test, label=values_test, fill=values_test))` but the resulting chart shows a color gradient:

[image]

However, I want only two different colors, one for each data series.

I've also tried using `color=as.factor(values_test)` but this yields 12 different colors, one for each age category in my combined dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dplyr::bind_rows` to combine the two dataframe with unique ids. You can then use `fill` in `aes` to give them different colors.

```
library(ggplot2)
df_combined = dplyr::bind_rows(df_test1, df_test2, .id = 'id')

ggplot(df_combined, 
      aes(x=ages_test, y=values_test, fill = id), label=values_test) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks= scales::breaks_extended(n=10), 
                     labels=scales::comma) +
  geom_text(hjust=.5, vjust=-1, size=3, aes(label=scales::comma(values_test)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! You helped me out yesterday as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796835/how-do-i-plot-months-with-integer-values-using-ggplot

Comment: How do I customize the colors? I tried adding the following `+ scale_color_manual(values=c('dark green','green'))` but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `scale_fill_manual` : `scale_fill_manual(values = c('dark green','green'))`

Comment: What resources did you use to learn R? I started about a week ago and I'm using different pieces of code to hack things together. It's not very efficient.

Comment: Lot of practice coding and lurking on stackoverflow has helped me learn R.

Comment: One last question. Do you know how I can fix the labels for the last two age cohorts on the x-axis? https://i.imgur.com/QglBHVh.png The labels are overlapping too much. I tried using `geom_text_repel(direction=y)` but it gives me an odd result: https://i.imgur.com/885eIje.png

Comment: Never mind. I got it. I had to remove `geom_text()` in order to use `geom_text_repel()` and now it's behaving correctly: https://i.imgur.com/uDXXRpd.png